# Changing html content for local application only

Tags: html, local

I want to organize my notes (on scientific articles).

- I want to be able save text and images notes for each article
- Save the pdf file
- Organize it into a hierarchy with a document somewhere with a content table containing the hierarchy of thematics and link to all articles
- I want to be able to move fast between articles (open note on an article fast)
- Add tags to filter the articles
- Add an importance level to filter articles

There is many softawre for that kind of thing but it's often difficult to combine pdf file and notes containing text and images and hierarchy and tags
And they are often not really customizable.

The best solution I can think of is to use html files to put the article contents, and other html files with links to the articles pages.

I currently use a python script that I call from command line with pdf download link and article name as argument
The script creates an empty html page for the article at the good place in the hierarchy, add link in the table of content html page, and the article link with his tags in a seperate file

What I would like to do is to have a button in my table of content html page which would allow me to add an article and so add and modify some files.

t's seems that a very specific case because I'm using web like technologies only to organize local files.

But I don't know how to do that and I don't know where to look. Could it be done with javascript or php ? Or may be use something like python dash to display the html page and run some python script in the background

Sorry for my english I'm not a native speaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some app on github that did almost what I want: trilium and pervane
But I didn't use them because they were to complicated for me to customize them to add new functionalities

I finally find a solution by using flask to render my local notes that are stores as html.